# Query based on custom field

Tags: wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I have made **custom fields** using [advanced custom field plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). It has a field name school which includes choices such as *arts,education,engineering*.
Now my problem is how can i **query** only those post who field is arts  using **wpdb**. sincerely i don't know **wpdb** works.
[image: custom fields].
Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using WP_Query over a direct mysql query. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

In your WP_Query arguments include the 'meta_key' and 'meta_value' parameters.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'      => 'school',
    'meta_value'    => 'arts'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a Wordpress `Global` Database Access Variable, if you want to executes database related opration than you must use `$wpdb`

more info :  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: How can i query this custom fields with this can you provide me with some pseudo codes ?

Comment: $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
print_r($myrows);